# Start Fragment from searchView onClick

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

I am attempting to start a Fragment in the `onSearchClick` listener of a `SearchView`. The Fragment starts just fine but within a second or two the open SearchView (which is iconified by default) collapses again automatically, and reclicking on the SearchView doesn't invoke neither onClose nor onClick. Also I should note I'm not using an ActionBar, just a Toolbar I customized, so I can't use any `MenuItem` methods.

Here's the code in the activity for the SearchView:

```
SearchView main_search = findViewById(R.id.testing_search);

        main_search.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                search_fragment = new GroupFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_activity, search_fragment).commit();
            }
        });

        main_search.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

And the `SearchView` in the layout:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/testing_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        app:defaultQueryHint="Search by course name or code"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="true"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/main_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/main_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/main_toolbar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in case anyone has this issue - just move the `onClose` and `onSearchClick` listeners for the SearchView into the `onCreateView` method of the fragment being added. That way the focus doesn't switch from the SearchView to the Fragment, as the SearchView is contained within the Fragment. Just start the Fragment as normal from the parent activity.

Fragment `onCreateView`:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false)
        val search : SearchView = v.findViewById(R.id.testing_search)
        val toolbar : Toolbar = v.findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar)

        search.setOnSearchClickListener {
            //Do whatever on click
        }

        search.setOnCloseListener {
            //Do whatever on close
            //this boolean is required
            false
        }

        return v
    }
```